# How transform CSV in python?

Tags: python, csv, format, transform

I have this csv :

```
 id1, var1, value1_id1,
 id1,var2, value2_id1,
 id2,var1, value1_id2,
 id2,var2, value2_id2,
```

How i can transform my csv to :

```
 id, var1, var2,
 id1, value1_id1, value2_id1,
 id2, value1_id2, value2_id2,
```

Comment: It is certainly good to have the example input and output. It would be easier to understand the question if you also explained a bit what the logic behind is. In this case it seems that the second column is meant to end up as the column name. What you seem to be looking for is pivot: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @de1

You should use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None) #import csv

df.columns = ['ID', 'VAR', 'VALUE','extra'] #defining the column header
data = df[['ID', 'VAR', 'VALUE']] #defining a new database without the extra column

data.pivot(index='ID', columns='VAR')
```

Comment: Tks you ! very easy with pivot ;)

Comment: @AlanENTEM Anytime :)